# Use where outside the Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering whether we can use **where** outside a function?
e.g.

```
fun::Int->Int
fun n = n + 1

main = do
     fun x where x = 30
```

Obviously it does't work when I compile it,

I want to declare x as local variable for **fun** only

Comment: The only reason this doesn't work is that the types don't match up. You *can* use `where` in this context - read the error message!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function has the wrong type to be used as the final expression in a `do` block. It needs to return an `Monad m => m Int` value, not simply an `Int`. As `main` (in its usual use) is required to be an `IO` action, this means `m` should be `IO`.

```
 fun :: Int -> IO Int
 fun n = return (n + 1)
```

A `let` would be more appropriate than a `where` in this case, though.

```
main = do
  let x = 30 in fun x
```

Now, `x` is in scope *only* for the call to `fun`. If you wrote

```
main = do
  let x = 30
  fun x
```

then `x` is technically in scope for the rest of the `do` block, not just the call to `fun`. Despite sharing the same keyword `let`, there is a distinct difference between a `let` in a `do` block and a regular `let` expression. (The relationship is that

```
do
  let name = value
  foo
```

is equivalent to

```
let name = value
in do
    foo
```

)

---

Note that `do` itself does *not* create a monadic value; it is simply syntactic sugar for various operators which *assume* monadic properties. A quick overview:

1. `do { x <- y; foo x; }` becomes `y >>= (\x -> foo x)`.
2. `do { foo; bar; }` becomes `foo >> bar`.
3. `do { let x = y; foo; }` becomes `let x = y in do foo`
4. `do foo` becomes `foo`.

Most relevant to your code is rule 4; a single expression in a `do` block is equivalent to the expression by itself, meaning you can strip the `do`. Only after the `do` block is desugared does Haskell begin to type-check the result.

Comment: Does it though?  Copy/pasting the OP's code into ghci works fine for me.  I'm curious as to what the error he reports is.

Comment: Ah, good point. I fixed the other error the OP didn't point out specifically, which is that `fun` has the wrong type to be used as it is in the `do` block.

Comment: Isn't that the requirement that `main :: IO ()`?  So having a `main :: IO a` would also be rejected by the compiler (unless I am misremembering something).

Comment: you nail it, thanks. Now I understand a bit about 'where and let  in'

Comment: `main` is just a name that can be bound to anything. If it is used as the entry point to a complete program, then it must be bound to an `IO` action for the program to run. Here, the more general monad constraint simply comes from the fact that it is bound to a value defined by a `do` block.

Comment: The Haskell2010 report simply says that a Haskell program must have a module `Main` that exports a name `main` with type `IO t`, whose return value of type `t` is ignored. `t` is not required to be `()`, but it's a good reminder that your program won't be affected by whatever value the root `IO` action returns.

Comment: Understood.  As an aside, it's perfectly valid (if not a bit arcane) to write main (which has the type `Int`) as OP did.  I guess is because of the monad instance for `(->)`?

Comment: Ah, OK. No, I think the reason is that no other features of the `do` syntax (specifically, `<-` or the implicit `>>`) or a monad (like a call to `return`) are used. `do fun x` gets reduced to simply `fun x`.